# Java EclipseLink EntityManger: Way to Ensure Connection Can be Established?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I'm using eclipselink 2.4 in a JAX-RS (Jersey) application.

In my base controller, I connect to my database, but since the entity manager only *really* connects when a query is executed, an exception is thrown.

Is there a way I could determine if I can connect to a database after I get the EntityManager object so that I can handle the exception myself (and fail over manually to another database).

**EDIT:** assume I cannot change the underlying DBMS at all.

Comment: I would say that if you want high availability of the DB, you would better off investing in clustering your DBMS using the mechanisms provided by it. That way you would be protected against failures during all of the application execution and not only at initialization (which is usually only a tiny fraction of the time).

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: No; as I said in the post I'm using JAX-RS (Jersey)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and run a query on startup for your application. However if it fails you are out of luck for the error handling I guess.

You should really get a clustered HA database.